# Skype bot (translation from VB) not working

Tags: c#, vb.net, bots, skype

I was following a tutorial on youtube on how to create a simple Skype bot. It was written in VB and with my limited knowledge I did my best to recreate it in C# 
I stumbled upon "handles" which I can only assume is related to the eventhandler in C#

This is the code I've got so far but when I message myself from another skype account it doesn't respond. I've made sure to accept the little popup on skype that allows 3rd party software.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Skype oSkype = new Skype();
    string trigger = "!";

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        oSkype.Attach(7, false);
        oSkype.MessageStatus += new _ISkypeEvents_MessageStatusEventHandler(oSkype_MessageStatus);
    }


    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void oSkype_MessageStatus(ChatMessage pMessage, TChatMessageStatus Status)
    {
        if (Status == TChatMessageStatus.cmsReceived || Status == TChatMessageStatus.cmsSent)
        {
            string msg = pMessage.Body;
            Chat c = pMessage.Chat;

            if (msg.StartsWith(trigger))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString() + ": " + pMessage.Sender.Handle + " sent you a message");
                msg = msg.Remove(0, 1).ToLower();


                if (msg == "test")
                {
                    c.SendMessage("Test");
                }
                else
                {
                    c.SendMessage("Unrecognizable command.");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The code from the tutorial that I was following had this instead:

```
oSkype_MessageStatus(pMessage as ChatMessage, Status as TChatMessageStatus) Handles oSkype.MessageStatus
```

The closest to what I could come to implement this in c# was to add the void to the eventhandler in public Form1() which you can see in my code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: looks ok. The issue is not in the code you have posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Skype4Com's chat functions are not supported in the newer Skype versions. They were deprecated somewhere in-between 2013-2014.

From Skype's blog post [***Feature evolution and support for the Skype Desktop API***](https://blogs.skype.com/news/2013/11/06/feature-evolution-and-support-for-the-skype-desktop-api/):

> *I’m happy to share that we will be extending support for two of the most widely used features – call recording and compatibility with hardware devices – until we determine alternative options or retire the current solution. **Although chat via third party applications, will cease to work as previously communicated.***

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I have worked with COM Skype bots, but your code seems to be fine.

Nevertheless, I would suggest you to move to a modern approach on bots. Please check out the new [Microsoft Bot Framework](https://docs.botframework.com/)